# Cant access repeater control from the code behind file

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

I m trying to add markers on the map using a repeater control but i cant seem to access the Repeater1 from the code behind file when i include it within a script tag

**Html**

```
<div id="map" style="height:400px"></div>                      
</script>
      <asp: Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server"></asp: Repeater >
</script>
```

**C#**

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {

                DataTable dt = this.GetData("Select accidentID,acc_lat,acc_long,acc_description from Accident_reports ");
                Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
                Repeater1.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

what am i doing wrong

```
    <script>
        <asp: Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                {
                    "title": '<%# Eval("accidentID") %>',
                    "lat": '<%# Eval("acc_lat") %>',
                    "lng": '<%# Eval("acc_long") %>',
                    "description": '<%# Eval("acc_description") %>'
            }
        </ItemTemplate>
            <SeparatorTemplate>
                ,
        </SeparatorTemplate>
        </asp: Repeater >
    </script>
```

This is the entire code i want the repeater to contain if i don't use script tags then i am allowed access to the repeater control in the code behind but using script tags i'm not

Comment: Are you getting any error? Can you share the message of the error here?

Comment: The name Repeater1 does not exist in the current context

Comment: the designer.cs file has this code protected global::System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Repeater1;
         which is underlined in red also says The name Repeater1 does not exist in the current

Comment: why do you have </script> after the repeater control, is the repeater inside a script block?

Comment: yes im tryingto get the output of the repeater onto a javascript variable

Answer (score 0):

Change your code in this way:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <%= "<script>" %>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        {
                "title": '<%# Eval("accidentID") %>',
                "lat": '<%# Eval("acc_lat") %>',
                "lng": '<%# Eval("acc_long") %>',
                "description": '<%# Eval("acc_description") %>'
        }
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <%= "</script>" %>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```